# New devices (MacBook Pro 2023 and iPhone SE) connect to WiFi, but not to the internet. Strangely, old Mac connects without problem

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro, wifi, internet

I have a two-months old MacBook Pro that runs Ventura v13.4 and a MacBook Pro from early 2015 running Monterey v12.6.3. I also have an iPhone SE bought two years ago.

The old Mac connects seamlessly to my home internet, but neither the new Mac nor the iPhone do, which makes me think the issue is correlated and has the same source. To be specific: the device connect to the Wifi, but don't connect to the internet. Furthermore, this is only happening with my home network. The devices connect to the internet network at work as usual.

On the Mac, a warning sign has appeared on the Wifi icon and it prompts me to restart the modem or contact the ISP. For the Mac, I tried what is recommended [on this site](https://osxdaily.com/2022/11/07/fix-wi-fi-internet-connection-problems-in-macos-ventura/) and for the iPhone did what is recommended [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204051#:%7E:text=Reset%20your%20network%20settings,%3E%20Reset%20%3E%20Reset%20Network%20Settings.) in both case to no avail. Both devices are running the latest version of their respective software.

What is this issue and how can I solve? I find intriguing that the old Mac is connecting without problem, while the more modern devices don't.

Comment: Maybe a DNS issue? Try `ping 8.8.8.8` from a Terminal window.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Just did that. It prints to stdout: ping: sendto: No route to host \n Request timeout for imp_seq 0

Comment: Before you try to ping out to the internet, see if you can ping your router *first.*  This will tell you if you're actually connected to the network.  `ping 192.168.1.1` is pretty default.  If you get the ipaddress from your old Mac, you can extrapolate your subnet your router will be XXX.XXX.XXX.1 (most likely)

Comment: Oh...and please post your ipaddress.

Comment: Check if your connections are randomising MAC addresses. That might be confusing the router somehow, as it thinks it's seeing a new device each time.